# Use data from two documents inside formula (not import data)

Tags: excel, google-sheets, spreadsheet, google-docs

I am transferring from MS Excel to Google Sheets. My Excel formula is:

```
=SUMIF(FIGURES!$C$7:$C$105,N7,FIGURES!$D$7:$D$105)
```

The `FIGURES` sheet is within the same MS Excel document.

Now I have two separate Google Sheets documents:
1. active.gsheet
2. figures.gsheet

How do I link/refer data from another Google Sheets document (I am not importing data, but using data in the formula)?

So if I am entering the formula inside of `active.gsheet`:

```
=SUMIF( [figures.gsheet]$C$7:$C$105,N7,[figures.gsheet]$D$7:$D$105)
```

Also not sure if the formula in Excel is the same structure as Google Sheets.

Comment: I just re-read what you are doing.  1. Am I right in thinking that a excel workbook with two sheets has become two separate google documents?    2. if so do they have to be separate?  If not move the sheets to both be in the same google spreadsheet by right clicking on the sheets tab and choosing "copy to".  Then you can use the technique and formula in my answer to create the formula you need.

Comment: Note I had a formulas in sheet A that referred to sheet B (both in the same workbook).  I right clicked on the tab and copied sheet A to a NEW google file.  The formula became #REF.  because of this I suspect formaulas in google sheets cannot refer to cells in other files.

Answer (score 0):

1. Am I right in thinking that a excel workbook with two sheets has become two separate google documents?
2. if so do they have to be separate?

If not move the sheets to both be in the same google spreadsheet by right clicking on the sheets tab and choosing "copy to". Then you can use the mouse to create references for you. This the easiest option.     Also, perhaps you should investigate why importing an excel workbook results in one sheet being created in multiple files

Formulas in google sheets cannot refer to cells in other files, without using a googel specific IMPORTRANGE function to get the data you are referring to.

I found [this](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/786/how-do-i-link-a-cell-in-google-spreadsheets-to-a-cell-in-another-document) which confirms it!

You would have to copy any data you want to refer to into the current file using IMPORTRANGE()

Comment: @pnuts  I hope you prefer my answer now I've re-read the question!

Comment: thanks for your revised approach. You are correct in saying that it has gone from 1 excel spreadsheet with 2 tabs to 2 separate google sheets. I see, so instead of referencing between documents, I have to import that specific data into the sheet using IMPORTRANGE(). correct?

Comment: No. See the link I gave in  my answer "I found this ".  It doesn't import data, it just allows data to be referenced in another file, and is a formula used only by google sheets.